# Use case for `function foo end` function declaration?

Tags: julia

A declaration like this one is legal:

```
julia> function foo end
foo (generic function with 0 methods)
```

However, besides a placeholder to centralize documentation (and I am not even sure):

```
module Foo

"""
    foo(...) functions

- foo(n::Int) : do something
- foo(n::Int,m::Int) : do other thing
"""
function foo end
```

I can not see the role/goal of such declaration.

Question: is there an illustrative use case?

Comment: I guess it's useful if you write a library using `foo`, and expect the user to "fill out" the needed methods, but it doesn't make sense to provide any default implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It is my feeling too.

Comment: see https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/methods/#Empty-generic-functions-1

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński I have not seen this section of the doc, my fault! If you want to write a short answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is explained in the Julia Manual in [Empty generic functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/methods/#Empty-generic-functions-1) section. There are two main uses:

- simplifying documentation or improvement of code readability;
- separation of interface definition from implementations.

A typical use case can be seen for definitions of `randn!` and `randexp!`. First empty generic functions are defined and are coupled with documentation string. Next methods for those functions are dynamically defined.

Another similar example to study is definition `randstring`.

Finally look at `strides` function. It is defined in *abstractarray.jl* as empty generic function and then used in the same file. But no methods are defined for this function in this file, other files e.g. *dense.jl* or *subarray.jl* define such methods.